# Issue in tool tip content

Tags: manual-testing

[image]

Coding is done in asp.net. Please see the tool tip.Cant that be properly aligned? developer is saying that it is asp's default property and cant do anything. I don't have any idea on coding side.

Comment: Do you get the same misalignment in every browser? Also, when you view the HTML what do you see?

Comment: Of course it can be modified?  The css can be overridden or you can customize the standard css.

Comment: @vincebowdren Actually I am testing that in Client machine. Only IE is available there. Its IE 9 there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can be properly aligned:

[image: Correctly-aligned tooltip]

If it's not properly aligned, my guess it's because there are line-breaks in the tooltip text in the HTML, something like this:

```html
<option value="3" title="(Heat
) Burns of scald. The effect of contact with hot substances. (Chemical)
burns, tissue damae resulting from the corrosive  action chemicals, fume,
etc., (acids, alkalies)">Burn 2</option>
```

That results in a tooltip looking something like your screenshot:

[image: Mis-aligned tooltip]

That's why I recommended you take a look at the HTML itself (right click on the screen and select View Source).

On the other hand, even if you look at the HTML it doesn't give you the full story of why it's like that. For example, I don't know if that tooltip is hard-coded, or if it's configurable by the user somehow?

Comment: I think its hard coded. I cant find it by viewing source